# How can i chek if two list contained surface pygame object are equal?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have programmed a game that finished when two list contained [`Sufaces`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) objects are equal but with operator `==` don't work

The goal of this code is cut an image in 9 part for view it as a grid

This a piece of code

```py
def resize_image(img,left,top,right,bottom):
    size=(left,top,right,bottom)
    subimg=img.crop(size)
    # transform PIL image in suface for work in pygame
    subimg=pygame.image.fromstring(subimg.tobytes(),subimg.size,subimg.mode)
    return subimg

def build_Image(N):
    images=laod_images() #function that loads two images
    img=images[0]
    img1=images[1]
    left=0
    top=0
    right=100
    bottom=100


    tab=emptyMatrix(N) #function that create a empty matrix
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if i==N-1 and j==N-1:
                img1 = resize_image(img1, left, top, right, bottom)
                tab[i][j] = img1

                pos[i][j]=(left,top) matrix that save coordinate of surface objects

            else:
                subimg = resize_immagine(img1, left, top, right, bottom)
                tab[i][j] =subimg

                pos[i][j]=(left,top)

            left += 100
            right += 100

        top+=100
        bottom+=100
        left=0
        right=100
    return tab

tab=build_Image()
tab1=build_Image()
print(tab==tab1) #print False
```

Comment: Then read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) to learn _why_ it doesn’t work.

Comment: You have to show some code. When comparing two lists of the same length that contain the same object, the comparison operator works. However, if you load the same image twice, two different _Surface_ objects will be generated. This objects are not equal.

Comment: @Pjay What does `resize_image` do? I think you have misunderstood the basic concept of _Surfaces_

Comment: I have updated the code .

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two lists of the same length that contain the same object in the same order, the comparison operator evaluates to `True`.
However, if you load the same image twice with [`pygame.image.load()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html), two different [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) objects will be generated. This objects are not equal.

Comment: Ok there is a method or function two compare this matrix?